# Hibernate correct cascade mapping

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, persistence

I'm new to hibernate, I managed to make it work with some tables and also foreign keys but I need to save a hierarchy of java objects and I have no clue about doing it the best way. I'll simplify my problem like this

a **Request** may produces 0..* **Response**

a **Response** is associated to 1 **Request**

a **Response** also has 2 **ResponseDetail** object

a **ResponseDetail** is associated to 1 **Response**

```
Class Request{
 @Id
 int reqId;
}

Class Response
{
 @Id
 int respId;

 @OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
 @JoinColumn(name = "reqId")
 Request req; //foreign key from request
 ResponseDetail rd1;
 ResponseDetail rd2;
}


Class ResponseDetail{
 ???
 int rdId;
 other stuff...
}
```

Now java-side i'll get some Response, set manually their Request object and I will need to save this response and automatically let hibernate save the ResponseDetail rd1 & rd2, and I honestly don't know how to proceed.

Ideally, i would need a way to use the save method of hibernate on some response and it will automatically save the ResponseDetail in the DB and set the reference in the rd1 and rd2 fields

What mapping should I use? How to reach my goal correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@Entity
class Request
{
   @OneToMany(mapped-by="request", cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
   public List<Response> getResponses()
   // implementation    

}

@Entity
class Response 
{
   @OneToOne
   @JoinColumn(name="request_id")
   public Request getRequest()
   // implementation
}
```

Before saving, in your service part, you should set the Parent object (Request in this example) for all childs object.

```
for(Resposne res:request.getResponses(){ 
    res.setRequest(request);
}
yourService.save(request);
```

Comment: Even if i'm not done, the annotation JoinColumn which I was missing helped. I tried a similar thing but without success, since I also need to serialize Request in json and it produced loops. So i tried to remove the Request field in Response and force an id, but still when I saved Request, i've got unique identifier constraint violation on the response fields (in Request), guess i'll have to study more